# Filter a listview instead of re-querying the database with more specific criteria

Tags: android, listview, filter, cursor

The subject doesn't seem to have been discussed a lot in details so I am gonna explain my situation as well as possible to make it clear and hopefully get some explanations.

My app allows the user to get information about places : there are different menus with different buttons corresponding to categories of places (food/ fastfood, restaurants, ... OR stores/shops, .... and so on). The user clicks on the button of his choice, it will send a request to my database and display a listview with the results. This way :
[image]
It is one example, but there are 16 possibilities like this, and everytime it's opening the same activity (ResultListViewActivity) but displaying different content.

I want the user to be able to make more accurate research, so there is a filter mode as you can see on picture 3. The window appearing allows to choose some more criteria. What I planned so far was to fill some variable everytime the user clicks on something. Like if he chooses to pay with a credit card, VALUECARD = X, if budget = something then VALUEBUDGET = Y and so on and when you click on OK it sends all the value package to a method querying the database and open a new listview with the results. It would definitely works, and I know how to do. But I also think it's not really a good way to query the database every time, why not searching directly in the list view ?

I know how to query the database, as my method is working to display listview (see picture 2), but I have no idea how to query a listview, especially when some columns from the database I would use in my filering are not imported in my cursor and then in my listview. I guess I would first have to import every column I might need for filtering.
Here is the code of my method displaying the listview so you see how my cursor is filled and my adapter is made :

```
private void displayListView() {

    // getExtra 
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    String title = bundle.getString("title", "Choose here :");
    String inInterval = bundle.getString("inInterval");
    Log.d(TAG, "inInterval = " + inInterval);

    poititle.setText(title);
    
    // put the results of the method in a cursor
    Cursor c = dbHelper.findPoiInTable(inInterval);
    String[] columns = new String[] { DatabaseAdapter.COL_NAME,
            DatabaseAdapter.COL_STREET, DatabaseAdapter.COL_WEBSITE,
            DatabaseAdapter.COL_TELEPHONE, DatabaseAdapter.COL_REMARKS,
            DatabaseAdapter.COL_PRICE };
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.name, R.id.street, R.id.website,
            R.id.telephone, R.id.remarks, R.id.price };
    cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.poi_info, c,
            columns, to, 0);
    

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.poilistview);
    // Assign adapter to ListView
    listView.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        // Comportement des éléments de la listview
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    POIActivity.class);

            String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name))
                    .getText().toString();
            String website = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.website))
                    .getText().toString();
            String telephone = ((TextView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.telephone)).getText().toString();
            String remarks = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.remarks))
                    .getText().toString();
            String price = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.price))
                    .getText().toString();
            // i.putExtra(ID_EXTRA, name) ;
            i.putExtra(ID_NAME, name);
            i.putExtra(ID_WEBSITE, website);
            i.putExtra(ID_TELEPHONE, telephone);
            i.putExtra(ID_REMARKS, remarks);
            i.putExtra(ID_PRICE, price);
            startActivity(i);
        }

    }); }
```

In this particular case, how could I for example filter the "COL_PRICE" which is in my cursor ? To be more precise, in my filter menu, when the user sets the budget and we get a value, how to use this value in relation to the value from COL_PRICE and keep elements under the given value ?
Thanks for any information !

Comment: You are talking about local database and not a server database right?

Comment: Yeah right, stored in the assets file ! Is it worth trying to filter the listview or requerying the database is ok in that case?

Comment: No anyway I thought you move it to the database directory already.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution with your current Code would be using adding a `FilterQueryProvider` to your adapter, but this will eventually start a new query in your database.

If you really don't want to do a new query on your database, you would have to implement your own custom adapter for your `ListView`. This will be a whole lot more work than the first solution and is probably slower too.